# `do-release-upgrade` is selecting 17.10 instead of 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

There was a bug fix awhile back for this problem: [`do-release-upgrade` selects 18.04 instead of 17.10 target](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006921/do-release-upgrade-selects-18-04-instead-of-17-10-target). My problem is the opposite of this bug fix.

On my test partition when I try to upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 and I run:

```
~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                       
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,253 kB]                                                              
Fetched 1,254 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                             
authenticate 'artful.tar.gz' against 'artful.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'artful.tar.gz'
```

It is selecting Artful (**17.10**) and not Bionic (**18.04**).

If I change `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` last line from:

```
Prompt=normal
```

to:

```
Prompt=lts
```

and rerun `do-release-upgrade` I get this:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Assuming 18.04 has been properly populated into Canonical Repositories, what am I doing wrong???

Comment: It takes several days (business days, aka monday thru friday days, and not just 'days' in general) for the 17.10 -> 18.04 release to be made 'normal' and offered that way.  If you're on 16.04, then it takes about a week after the 18.04.1 release until that upgrade path is directly available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal; it will take some time before the new release is offered that way.

If you want to do it now, try:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: Haha it's like I already knew that but forgot :(

Comment: From `man  do-release-upgrade`: `-d, --devel-release`  If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release. So until the 'CC' will be the development release, this will point to 18.04  LTS alias 'Bionic Beaver'.